# How to get the same submit command across multiple queuing environments easily?

Tags: centos, cluster-computing, job-scheduling, sungridengine

Is there any set of standard commands for queuing systems ?
I know no-one expects shell scripts to be portable, but why can't OpenLava, SunGridEngine, Platform LSF etc agree to use a common set of commands for common queuing tasks like job submission?

I shouldn't have to learn about qsub, bsub etc since they do the same thing from a user's POV.

Has someone made wrappers to accomplish the goal of cluster-platform-agnostic job submission across multiple hosts?

google search suggests that no one has set up such a standardized platform or even started agitating for it:
https://www.google.com/search?q=posix+queueing+standard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=cluster+queueing+standard&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official

tentakel and jobscheduler also look like interesting packages, but neither of them is part of CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is [DRMAA](http://www.drmaa.org/).  I know both SGE and LSF support DRMAA, but it's not a uniform submit script, rather it's a uniform library.

This common submit is a common problem in the Grid universe.  There have been many solutions, such as:

- Generic Job language that is translated, such as RSL (globus) and JSL (Job specification language standard, implemented by few grid middlewares).
- Translate one submit language into another, or many others.  Such as Condor's [batch universe](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v8.1/5_3Grid_Universe.html#SECTION00635000000000000000).

Grid Middleware seems heavy handed for your usecase.  Something like [Bosco](http://bosco.opensciencegrid.org/) may work for you.  Or just plain old Condor (only have to learn Condor language to submit to PBS, LSF, or SGE).

But you are right, each scheduler comes up with their own submission language, and there is not unified method for submitting to any.

Comment: Is DRMAA on its way to becoming some sort of IEEE or POSIX-type standard? DRMAA looks convenient, but has the cluster community united around 'The Open Grid Forum'? How long will DRMAA be used? 'at' and 'queue' have been been in unix for a long time but 'at' is better for building other things so gets used more.

Comment: I'm not sure on DRMAA's goals of becoming a IEEE or POSIX standard.  The community has not united around the Open Grid Forum, though most scheduler developers pay attention to the OGF.  DRMAA has been around for a long time, maybe more than a decade.  It will probably be around for a while.